# Postgresql with Entity Framework 6 (database first approach)

Tags: c#, mysql, database, postgresql, entity-framework-6

Is it possible to use `EF6` with `Postgresql` database but using database first approach? I found some solution that requires manually writing c# classes based on db structure that is unsatisfactory for me. I would like use it like `Sql server`, so I choose server and database from list, then I choose tables which I want to use and *voilà* .

What I did is installing `npgsql`. I can add this database in Server Explorer tab, but when I want to create `ADO.NET` Entity Model I can't find this database in list.

Comment: Does this help https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/wiki/Visual-Studio-Design-Time-Support---DDEX-Provider

Comment: Fixed typo, technologies highlighting, changed tag to be more specific.

Comment: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/806698/6134234/6d22ea82-b125-11e4-9426-96a62ff6b2ff.PNG

Unfortunately I'm getting error 
"Your project references the latest version of Entity Framework....". I tried different versions of EF and npgsql, installing npgsql throught nuget as well as manually selecting reference from C:\Program Files (x86)\The Npgsql Development Team\Npgsql\Npgsql-2.2.4.3-net45 and such error displays me every time. At the moment I have installed EF 6.1.3 and npgsql 2.2.4.3 (npgsql.ef 2.2.4.3 also).

Comment: My mistake was adding second listening (<system.data> block) to App.config . Now it's fine, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible. First, add this extension to Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition (the IDE I used): **Npgsql PostgreSQL Integration**

[image: Npgsql PostgreSQL Integration]

Then, using Nuget package manager, add:

- **EntityFramework6.Npgsql**
- **Npgsql**

And then you can proceed to add your ado.net entity data model/ database. Tables will be added nicely but I had a challenge with functions and views.